# How to disable or customize <input type="date"> on different mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, mobile-safari

So there are a few things I would like to know how to do, control, and fix:

(1) I can't seem to figure out how to disable the scroll wheel that shows up on mobile device browsers only for **[input type="date"]** Everything I've found that also works for [input type="number"] works, but only on web browsers, not mobile.

(2) There is a situation where I want the scroll wheel to be available, however, I'm not able to use the MAX property [(found here)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date) effectively not only on mobile browsers, but with Safari's web browser also. (IE it only works on Firefox and Chrome's web browser). It seems mobile browsers just respond completely different to the jQuery handlers.

(3) The scroll wheel on mobile devices, regardless of whether it's Safari or Chrome, has the up/down/exit button partially cut off by the scroll wheel. I'm not sure how to debug this, if I need to use css margin to fix it, or what, because I simply don't know what DIVs are being used (if any) and what's going on when used on mobile devices. I'm assuming something with Webkit?

Any insight or help on this would be appreciated. Below are some screenshots. Thanks so much!

---

**This shows the up/down/exit button partially cut off by the scroll wheel on Chrome mobile. It does the same on Safari mobile.**

### [image]

**This shows the MAX feature working on Chrome's web browser (Max is set to 1998)**

[image: Screenshot1]

Comment: It is faked by using `type="text"` instead of `type="date"`. For cross-browser compatibility see here the mess: https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime. Read the notes, You are right for Safari it is only partially supported.

Comment: For sure, but that means I have to run validation to only accept numbers and "/" also right? I ran across this earlier, and was curious of your thoughts about it being a viable alternative: https://demo.mobiscroll.com/jquery/datetime/date-picker#

Comment: Correct, look at the source code of the [jQuery-UI Datepicker](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/widgets/datepicker.js) there is a LOT of work to get it cross-browser. I am using a jQuery-UI Datepicker skinned for mobile: https://plnkr.co/edit/gJnaZT2QHPBUtRgVFv3s?p=preview